# accessoryType Checkmark indents UITableViewCell to the left

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

When i select a cell in my tableview, the cell was pushed to the left by the accessoryTypeCheckMark.

my custom cell was programmatically inserted into a tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                     indexPath];
    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want contents of the cell to indent when the checkmark is visible...

Comment: Hi jasarien, that's right! Thanks

Comment: @zerlphr I know this question is pretty old but will comment for future readers. The solution is add the constraint to the cell itself instead of the contentView

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the contents of your cell (more specifically, depending on how far to the right the text extends), the contents will be re drawn to make room for the check mark to appear.

If you don't want the text to move, you'll need to draw cell contents yourself using a custom cell subclass.

Comment: Hmm, I tried reducing the length of my UILabel in custom cell by 50 but it doesn't eliminate the indentation

Comment: Laying out your own subviews doesn't help. Showing a checkmark will still indent subviews.

Comment: @VictorBogdan The checkmark next to this answer appears to disagree with you. In my own experience, this is how I've solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was tearing my hair out over this too but luckily I was able to turn on the left side autoresizing constraint for my subview in Interface Builder, to keep it aligned to the left of the cell.  The width and right side constraints are disabled.  In my case, this keeps a 100 pixel wide UIView pinned to the left of the cell regardless of whether UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark is shown, and also keeps its width constant even if the table cell width changes.

Comment: That's not an optimal solution, try going into portrait mode and see what happens.